# Custom keyboard map in Gnome (on ArchLinux)

Tags: gnome, keyboard-layout, xkb

I've just switched from LXDE to Gnome and I'm struggling with configuring the keyboard the way I want it.  The Swedish keyboard layout is painful when programming (e.g. `{[]}` require right-hand finger acrobatics) so I've remapped them using `xkbcomp`.

Under LXDE/LXDM I could have the mapping happen automatically on login by putting it in `~/.xprofile`.  This doesn't work under Gnome/GDM though.  `/etc/gdm/Xsession`, which GDM uses to launch `gnome-session`, does source `~/.xprofile`, but by the time I'm logged in and starting a terminal the mappings have been undone.  I'm guessing something that `gnome-session` or one of its cohorts undoes my careful changes to the keyboard map.

I suppose I need to somehow make my changes at a later stage in the login process, but I've not managed to find a way to achieve that.  How can I do that?

(Alternatively, is there a way to add user keyboard layouts that get picked up by the Gnome3 keyboard layout settings dialogue?  Or failing that, how can I add layouts in the system?)

Comment: Have you tried using `.bashrc` or `.profile`?

Comment: I have tried running `/etc/gdm/Xsession` in a login shell with no luck.  Just adding it to either of those files will require that I start a terminal before the mappings are active, which isn't ideal since I do quite a bit of my development in Eclipse.

Comment: Adding it to `~/.profile` should cause it to be run on login, adding it to `~/.bashrc` will require a terminal since it is only read for non-login shells. See [here](http://lfsbook.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/6.3/postlfs/profile.html).

Comment: The big question is *when* during login. When looking more closely at my system's `/etc/gdm/Xsession` it sources both `~/.profile` and `~/.xprofile` (in that order), so moving stuff from `~/.xprofile` to `~/.profile` is pointless. Unless of course, `gnome-session` itself sources `~/.profile` but not `~/.xprofile`, which it doesn't according to my tests just now.

Comment: Hmm... OK, how about the ugly hack of making eclipse an alias to something like `source ~/.xprofile && ecplipse`?

Comment: That's not such a good suggestion.  First of all since `alias` is a shell concept, so it's completely unnecessary.  Second because I use other graphical tools where I also want the mappings to exist, gvim, gedit, libreoffice, etc... that means I'd have to copy all the relevant `.desktop` files into `~/.local/share/applications` and modify them, so I can start either of them as the first tool after logging in.  No, what is needed is some convenient way to run a script automatically after logging in, like `~/.xprofile` works in LXDE/LXDM.

Comment: You're quite right, that's why I called it an "ugly hack" :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly me!  After a bit of thinking I found a good and easy way of doing it:

1. Copy the contents of `~/.xprofile` into a script somewhere.  Make sure it's executable.
2. Start `gnome-session-properties` and add a new startup program.  Point it to the script.

That's it.

Much easier than fiddling around with special dot-files that are sourced on login, really :)